# OpenSSH 8.2 PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes - bad key types for FIDO/U2F in sshd_config

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh, ubuntu-18.04, u2f

Recently updated to OpenSSH 8.2 on both client (Ubuntu Desktop 18.04) and server (Ubuntu Server 18.04) in order to test the new FIDO/U2F token functionality.

Currently running into an issue when updating my server's /etc/sshd_config.

I updated PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes with `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com` (attempted both with/without the +)

This causes restarting SSH to fail, and is only remediated if I remove the two *sk-* key types from sshd_config.

Running `journalctl -xe` post failure shows an exit code with *'+Bad key types sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com'.*

I confirmed via `ssh -Q key` that those key types are valid.

Am I missing something obvious? Any help greatly appreciated.